# Testing java class using selenium and cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testing, cucumber

[image]user should be able to select the preferred language
and content of the web site should be loaded with the selected language using followng web site?

This is my current code how I Modify to match this scenario?

```
ublic class Steps {             

    WebDriver driver;           
            
    @Given("^Open the Firefox and launch the application$")                 
    public void open_the_Firefox_and_launch_the_application() throws Throwable                          
    {       
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E://Selenium//Selenium_Jars//geckodriver.exe");                    
       driver= new FirefoxDriver();                 
       driver.manage().window().maximize();         
       driver.get("https://www.gov.lk/welcome.html");                   
    }       

    @Then("^Reset the credential$")                 
    public void Reset_the_credential() throws Throwable                             
    {       
       driver.findElement(By.name("btnReset")).click();                 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Which language are you trying to click on _first_, _second_ or `English`?

Comment: English first...

Comment: You want to click on English, that's your scenario, right?

Comment: yes.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.english"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='english']"))).click();
  ```